# Setting up a Movesense development environment on Linux

Tags: movesense

I followed an instruction to set up a Movesense development environment, "Manual setup on Linux", from *[Suunto / Movesense-community / Movesense-device-lib, README.md](https://bitbucket.org/suunto/movesense-device-lib/src/523308c2b380fcde46d51af9af2f9ed17907ab55/README.md)*

However, I got stuck at `sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-embedded`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gcc-arm-embedded
```

How can I move forward?

I used [Ubuntu 17.10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_17.10_.28Artful_Aardvark.29) (Artful Aardvark) as a guest OS.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the repository:

```
sudo apt-get remove gcc-arm-none-eabi gdb-arm-none-eabi binutils-arm-none-eabi
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:team-gcc-arm-embedded/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Tried those three lines, but the issue remains:
tam@tam-VirtualBox:~$ sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-embedded
.....
E: Unable to locate package gcc-arm-embedded

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded it directly from ARM IIRC:
https://developer.arm.com/open-source/gnu-toolchain/gnu-rm/downloads

Following the instructions under "GNU/Linux" in the "GNU ARM Embedded Toolchain" section of
https://gnu-mcu-eclipse.github.io/toolchain/arm/install/#gnu-arm-embedded-toolchain

Summarized:

```
// Get some support dependencies for 32 bit running on 64-bit machines
// Check toolchain README for actual list.
$ sudo apt-get -y install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0

// Install the toolchain
$ mkdir -p "${HOME}"/opt
$ cd "${HOME}"/opt
$ tar xjf ~/Downloads/gcc-arm-none-eabi-7-2017-q4-major-linux.tar.bz2
$ chmod -R -w "${HOME}"/opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi-7-2017-q4-major
```

You will likely have to modify some of the build files in the Movesense project to point to this location for it to build.

The following might also be helpful: *[How to install a functional ARM cross-GCC toolchain on Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic Beaver)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/453032/how-to-install-a-functional-arm-cross-gcc-toolchain-on-ubuntu-18-04/480007#480007)*

I had some trouble installing it on a Windows machine and tried out [Vagrant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vagrant_%28software%29). This makes the development environment highly movable and in sync if you have multiple developers working on the project.

Comment: The first link redirects to [https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/gnu-rm/downloads](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/gnu-rm/downloads) ("/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools" instead of "/open-source").